# Volume not loud enough [Ubuntu 16.04.1]

Tags: 16.04, sound, volume-control

I have an Asus ROG G551JX running Ubuntu 16.04.1. Don't know if it is a side effect of something I did or something else. I booted into Ubuntu yesterday and started playing music. Took me a few seconds to realize that the volume was damn low. I checked the volume control but everything was maxed out. Tried messing within volume control and the only thing that made a change was allowing the max volume to go beyond 100% but then, the sound started to crackle which was not what I wanted and what I used to hear before.

I run a dual-boot config with Windows 10 and just to confirm I wasn't hallucinating, I booted into Win and the volume was as loud as it used to be. But switch to Ubuntu and it's very low. Headphone volume seems to be alright at max.

I tried messing with `alasamixer` but everything seemed fine there. Anyone know what might be the cause of this and what the fix would be? For the record, I'm 100% sure that I had the same level of volume when I first installed Ubuntu 2 weeks back.